# java script function for only numeric value and default "0"

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Below is my text box in `MVC` application's view.
I want that when its loaded it has default value "0"and its allow only digit.So how its possible with only one common function.When user kept it blank it 'ill automatic get default value.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => item.myfeild, new { placeholder = "Required", @class = "myclass", require = "true", maxlength = "1", id = @item.myid })
```

Comment: If you have the data type of your property as "int" in your View, then it should do this automatically for you.

Answer (score 1):

> Use This Function write event in textbox

```
onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);"

function isNumberKey(evt) {
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;
return true;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
first change your id name to myfeild like this :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => item.myfeild, new { placeholder = "Required", @class = "myclass", require = "true", maxlength = "1", id = "myfeild" })
```

then use this script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($("#myfeild").val() == "") {
            $("#myfeild").val('0');
        }
        $("#myfeild").keydown(function (event) {
            if ($("#myfeild").val() == "0") {
                $("#myfeild").val('');
            }
            if (event.shiftKey) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39) {
            }
            else {
                if (event.keyCode < 95) {
                    if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            }
         });
            $("#myfeild").keyup(function (event) {
                if ($("#myfeild").val() == "") {
                    $("#myfeild").val('0');
                }
             });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code. This may help you:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("#yourElementId").val().length < 1)
        $("#yourElementId").val(0);

    $("#yourElementId").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    $("#yourElementId").blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length < 1)
            $(this).val(0);
    });

});

</script>
```